# Android's StickyGridHeader click listener issue

Tags: android, gridview

I use StickyGridHeader open source and it works well.
Now I would like to add an `ImageView` in the header to do something,
so I wrote some code like this:

```
public class AAA extends CursorAdapter implements StickyGridHeadersSimpleAdapter 
{
    ...

    @Override
    public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
    ...
    ImageView bbb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bbb);
    }
}
```

But once I added a click listener for `bbb`, it didn't work.
Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Use ViewHolder Pattern for HeaderView. I recommend to use this library https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Comment: thanks for the link. but my program is mainly for imageview, so I prefer to use StickyGridHeader instead of StickyListHeader